# Blame for Google Drive documents

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I am trying to write Google document add-on which will help me to check who wrote particular part of the document, in my work every day several people edit the same document and very often instead of putting the names they write sentences like: "I did this..." or "I bought it already..." and we can not know figure out who did what.

Let's imagine below is a sample text/paragraph from a document on google drive:

> line 1 (created by person A)
>
> line 2 (created by person B)
>
> line 3 (created by persons A and B)

How with Google drive SDK or another API get blame functionality like in Git. In other words, I would like to have a list of the last author(s) of an each line of text in Google drive document.

Comment: I'd love this feature to be developered!